# Wicd break my internet connection on RPI3B

Tags: wifi, internet, wicd-curses

I have RPI3B and I am getting terrible experiences while trying to put it online.

At my place I have access to network with cable (I need to change MAC) and to secured wifi. Both works with all other devices.

**Initial state**

After install, I can see the wifi networks around, but the one I need was greyed out. It seems to be pretty common issue with RPI here. so I tried to follow all tutorials I found here - with no success.

At this moment I was able to change my eth0 MAC and connect at least with cable.

**After installation of Wicd**

I thought it can be smart idea to install Wicd. I can see the wifi I need with Wicd-curses, but it does not connect (all security settings are correct - I test it on other devices). Problem is, now I cannot connect with cable - it just do not connect, with no error (with changed MAC).

**After un-installation of Wicd**

Now I cannot see any wifi, nor I can connect with cable (if I change MAC). The wifi selections shows something "no wifi interface found" although accoding the `ifconfig` eth0 and wlan0 are both up.

**Problem**

Where could be a problem? Can I somehow purge the mess after Wicd? What else instead of Wicd I can try to make the internet working on RPI?

I would like to avoid reinstalling rasspbian, because yesterday I went through the same scenario with wicd and after SD card formating I did something wrong what results bricked SD card (https://askubuntu.com/questions/894095/cannot-format-sd-card-with-ubuntu/894227#894227)

Get RPI online seems to be really expensive and exhausting fun at the end.

Comment: This is a rant which makes no sense. There is no question, and you have provided no information.

Comment: @Milliways Thanks for response. What information is needed? I can provide any information that can help to find solution.

Comment: By far the easiest solution here is to re-image your SD card and start over. I'd suggest that the above isn't really the question you should be asking, which is '[How do I reformat my SD card without destroying it?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/)'. You're almost certainly going to have to do it at some point, so it would be a good idea to figure out what went wrong with your bricked card. I'm also a little mystified as to why you'd need to change your MAC addresses - are you spoofing past ISP restrictions?